# Understanding Variance

Tags: error-function

I have to analyse the reasons that we did not meet target.

Our target is 4750 m
Our target speed is 500m/hr
Our target hrs are 9.5

We achieved a speed of 550 m/hr
We achieved hrs of 9.1
We achieved a total of 5005m

So Variance of +50 m/hr
Variance of -0.4 hrs
Variance of +255m

How do I calculate the variance caused by Speed and the Variance caused by hours?